# Finding which printer or user is crashing spooler

Tags: windows-server-2012, service, print-server, printing

I have a Windows Server 2012 print server that is having the Print Spooler `c:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe` crash.  The Application Log in Event Viewer shows me that the crashing .DLL is LMUD1PLANG.DLL which belongs to the Lexmark Universal Print Driver.  I have more than dozen printers that use this driver.  It would be useful to narrow this down to which printer is causing the crash.  Is there anyway to see the printer that caused it?  Is there a way to see the actual print job or user that sent it that crashed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easy way is not very exact, but if you enable general logging on print jobs, you can narrow it way down and usually figure out the culprit pretty quickly by correlating which jobs were being processed with the time the spooler crashed.

[On 2012, there are even specific diagnostic print logging options you can enable](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13308.troubleshooting-windows-server-2012-printing.aspx), for everything from drivers to the printing subsystem itself, and those are invaluable in  tracking down precisely which printer or workstation is crashing your print server if you have a busy environment for printing.  Follow the link for more detail, because there's just far too much information to post here.